# how to prevent from going back to login page after logging in

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have developed a website in php. The index.php is a login form. After logging in dashboard.php is coming. But when I press the back button in the browser it is redirecting to the login page. How to prevent it. If there is any solution please tell. Thanks in advance. The codes are given below:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('https://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HD-Black-Picture.jpg');">

    <section id="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-7 co2">
                            <h1 class="h1">Orbit Shifters Employee Site</h1>
                            <h2 class="h2">Login Here <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i></h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 co1">
                            <form method="post" action="func.php">
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" class="i1" placeholder="Enter Your Username">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="i1" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn1">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

func.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login");
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', 'root', '');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $query="select * from signup where username='$username' and password='$password';";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
    {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        $_SESSION['status']="Active";
        header("Location:dashboard.php?name=".$row['name']);
        exit;
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Enter Correct Details!!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php', '_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if($_SESSION['status']!="Active")
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
else{
    $name=$_GET['name'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/f3/af/e5f3af2b9186af6e86187c84f4ad930e.jpg);">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="dashboard.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>">Dashboard</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="li1"><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section id="dashboard">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row ro1">
                <p class="p1"> Hello <?php echo $name; ?>, Welcome to Orbit Shifters EMployee Site.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ro1">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col2">
                    <a href="project1.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>"><button class="btn btn2">Project 1 <br>Report <br>Submission</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col2">
                    <button class="btn btn2">Project 2 <br>Monthly Report <br>Submission</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col2">
                    <button class="btn btn2">Project 3 <br>Feedback <br>Submission</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
}
 ?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['status']);
header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Comment: You should exit after setting the header

Comment: and your logout code is superfluous, session_destroy and a redirect would suffice

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but what if you add a check at the beginning of the `index.php` file that would redirect you to the dashboard if you are logged in ? Something like this

```
// index.php
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status'] === "Active") {
    header("location: dashboard.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
```

this way, if you click back in the browser, you will still go to index.php, but then you will be redirected to the dashboard again if you are already logged in